# Change facet title position in Altair?

Tags: python, altair

How can I move the facet titles (in this case, year) to be above each plot? The default seems to be on the side of the chart. Can this be easily changed?

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

df = data.seattle_weather()

alt.Chart(df).mark_rect().encode(
    alt.Y('month(date):O', title='day'),
    alt.X('date(date):O', title='month'),
    color='temp_max:Q'
).facet(
    row='year(date):N',
)
```

[image: problematic plot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A general solution for this is to use the `labelOrient` option of the `header` parameter:

```
df = df[df.date.dt.year < 2014]  # make a smaller chart

alt.Chart(df).mark_rect().encode(
    alt.Y('month(date):O', title='day'),
    alt.X('date(date):O', title='month'),
    color='temp_max:Q'
).facet(
    row=alt.Row('year(date):N', header=alt.Header(labelOrient='top'))
)
```

[image: heatmap with two years of data and labels on top]

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to remove the row specification and set the facet to have a single column

```py
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

df = data.seattle_weather()

alt.Chart(df).mark_rect().encode(
    alt.Y('month(date):O', title='day'),
    alt.X('date(date):O', title='month'),
    color='temp_max:Q'
).facet('year(date):N', columns=1)
```

[image]