# Hiding facet row or column headers

Tags: python, charts, altair

How can I hide the row (or column) header labels in a facet chart?

I rotated the labels by 45 degrees in the following example ([copied from this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52360965/change-facet-title-position-in-altair:)) to highlight which ones I mean, the year numbers:

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

df = data.seattle_weather()

alt.Chart(df).mark_rect().encode(
    alt.Y('month(date):O', title='day'),
    alt.X('date(date):O', title='month'),
    color='temp_max:Q'
).facet(
    row=alt.Row(
        'year(date):N',
        header=alt.Header(labelAngle=45)
    )
)
```

[image: plot]

Comment: A possible hack is `labelFontSize=0` but that seems like a bad approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way to do this is to turn off the labels by setting `labels=False`:

```
header=alt.Header(labels=False)
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks like the most readable and suitable solution.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is to use a `labelExpr` containing an empty string:

```
header = alt.Header(labelExpr="''")
```